# Running in Windows CE from debugger causing eventual out-of-memory crash

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, serial-port, windows-ce

I'm building a C# application for a Windows CE machine. The CE machine is talking to a serial device, and I'm using the SerialPort class.

When I run the project from Visual Studio by right-clicking and deploying, it will run fine for fifteen to twenty minutes before slowing down and eventually crashing from running out of memory, but when I deploy the solution and run it locally from the CE machine (navigate to the folder, open the exe), it runs fine for a whole day, which is as long as I've tried it.

I don't know why. I've tried building for release and debug, and it makes no difference. The only thing that seems to is where it's run from. I've also tried profiling the application using dotTrace, and it appears that it's being deployed to the CE machine before profiling starts; in any case, I can't reproduce the bug while the profiler is running.

I've also tried packaging the code that's handling the serial stream into a DLL, thinking that maybe Visual Studio was messing with something inside of it while debugging, but that didn't change anything, either.

Is there anything I can do to increase the stability of running from the IDE? I like being able to debug with it, but the inconsistency makes me feel like I might be doing something wrong.

Comment: The conclusion we've come to at work is that it's a part of the problems surrounding .Net 3.5's SerialPort class. Replacing it with a C++ library seems to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as we've been able to tell, the problem I described is related to the SerialPort class from System.IO.Ports. I think it might be related to some of the problems described [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/Vsexpressvb/thread/3e64f562-e74b-4213-8019-e69f54fc0d74); the managed SerialPort class calls into WinAPI code that's unmanaged inside of a loop, something goes wrong, and that unmanaged memory is lost.